# É seguro confiar nos valores de $_SERVER["HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP"]?

Tags: php

E seguro confiar diretamente nos valores da variável $_SERVER["HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP"], há necessidade de filtrar ou sanitizar ela?

E seguro utilizar ela assim?

```
$resposta = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=".$chave_secreta."&response=".$captcha_data."&remoteip=".$_SERVER["HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP"])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isto é seguro somente se estiver usando CloudFlare, e além disso, estiver apenas expondo sua conexão para o CloudFlare.

---

Em geral, você deve recursar qualquer conexão, de qualquer lugar, exceto para os IPs mencionados em https://www.cloudflare.com/pt-br/ips/.

---

Se estiver usando NGINX, pode usar algo como o código abaixo para tal finalidade de restringir o acesso externo ao CF:

```
allow 2400:cb00::/32;
allow 2606:4700::/32;
allow 2803:f800::/32;
allow 2405:b500::/32;
allow 2405:8100::/32;
allow 2a06:98c0::/29;
allow 2c0f:f248::/32;

allow 173.245.48.0/20;
allow 103.21.244.0/22;
allow 103.22.200.0/22;
allow 103.31.4.0/22;
allow 141.101.64.0/18;
allow 108.162.192.0/18;
allow 190.93.240.0/20;
allow 188.114.96.0/20;
allow 197.234.240.0/22;
allow 198.41.128.0/17;
allow 162.158.0.0/15;
allow 172.64.0.0/13;
allow 131.0.72.0/22;
allow 104.16.0.0/13;
allow 104.24.0.0/14;

deny all;
```

Comment: Essa variável pode ser alterada pelo usuário de modo que ele consiga fazer algum ataque? por exemplo xss.

Comment: Ela só pode ser alterada se a conexão for feita externamente ao CloudFlare. Você mesmo pode estar isso rodando um `curl -H "Host: seusite.com" -H "HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP: QualquerCoisa" https://seusite.com` e fazer o mesmo usando o IP direto (ao invés do site, via CF). Ao utilizar o CloudFlare, ele será responsável por substutir o valor do cabeçalho e o visitante não conseguirá mudar arbitrariamente. Mas, como mencionei na resposta, se você permitir conexões externas (nesse caso, você pode usar o IP direto) o visitante pode alterar o valor do cabeçalho arbitrariamente.